# Re: Permissions - who is the owner of a PHP script being executed on the server?

Tags: php, security, permissions, ownership

I'm having trouble understanding permissions and ownership in PHP.  I have a PHP script that writes images (uploaded by the client) to a folder.  The script will fail unless I set the permissions of that folder to 777.  I thought that since the script was being run by the server, it should only need 'owner' permissions?  Why do I need public write permissions?  And what exactly are group permissions?

Comment: You may want to [read this](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

You need to give public permissions in the case where the web server UID (user) is different from the UID (user) who owns the directory. If you have control over your server then you have 2 options.

1. Change the owner of the directory to the same UID (user) as the web server runs as.
2. Change the UID (user) that the web server runs as to match the owner of the directory.

Are you running your own server or is hosting provided by a third party?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who is running your server (I am assuming you are using apache httpd).  In phpinfo() you can see what user is running your server (search for something like User/Group) and if you set the owner of the folder to that user and give it write ability it should work.